# does anyone know the file location of fifo.c linux fifo scheduler?

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduler

I am trying to implement FIFO scheduler by myself in 3.12 kernel , I am not able to find the location of FIFO file ... like rt.c is at /kernel/sched/rt.c

Answer (score 0):

Which scheduler are you looking for?

Linux has lots of different schedulers, depending on the use case. For example, there are various schedulers for processes, block devices, networking and other drivers such as USB. Consequently, there is more than one simple fifo scheduler.

To name a few locations:

- [kernel/sched](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/sched) for process schedulers
- [net/sched/](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/sched) for networking schedulers
- [block/](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/block) for block device schedulers
- [drivers/usb/host/](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/usb/host) for USB host schedulers

The [Completely Fair Scheduler (CFS)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt), introduced with Linux 2.6.23, has a real-time scheduling class named `SCHED_FIFO`.

Anyway, I suggest to read some articles about Linux schedulers before doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for `<linux/kfifo.h>`